# 3 Input Logical OR with Numpy where

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have data frame like below  and i trying a new column with 3 inputs which are avialable .

I am looking for easy or other alternative to my code.

```
df.head()
John    Smith   Liya
0        0      1
1        0      0
1        1      1
1        0      1
0        1      1
1        1      0
0        0      0


Expected Output
    John    Smith   Liya    Result
    0        0       1      Liya
    1        0       0      John
    1        1       1      John/Smith/Liya
    1        0       1      John /Liya
    0        1       1      Smith/Liya
    1        0       1      John/Smith
    0        0       0      Nobody

**My code**

df['Result']=np.where(df['John']==1,('John' )),
             np.where(df['Smith']==1,( 'Smith')),
             np.where(df['Liya']==1,( ' Liya')),
             np.where((df['John']==1 and df['Smith']==1) ,('John/Smith'))
```

Is there an another easy way doing this in python?

Comment: Why are you using integers instead of booleans for this?! What is this for? I’m thinking that there has to be a better way of doing this, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can do `dot` , nobody here will just be blank , which will save the memory

```
df.dot(df.columns+'/').str[:-1]
0               Liya
1               John
2    John/Smith/Liya
3          John/Liya
4         Smith/Liya
5         John/Smith
6                   
dtype: object
```

Comment: Then I replace blank with the my required text

Comment: @snehanair that is fine as well, however I will recommend keep it as blank :-)

Comment: I have 10 columns in my dataframe , so how will I select only required  ones and pass it .

Comment: Getting an error`can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: @snehanair df.eq(1).dot(df.columns+'/')